# Type of container dynamic array (the size of the array is defined as arguments of the constructor)

Tags: c++, class, oop

The task is to:

1. Create the `abstract class Train` nd two derived `Passenger`/`Freight`.
2. Create a container. Type of container dynamic array (the size of the array is defined as arguments of the constructor).
3. Save the results to the file and delete them from it.
4. Search in the container and print the train by his number.

I have some questions about where is better to create `userInput`, `storeToArray` functions. In the menu file or class as a virtual function or create one more h/cpp?

Why does is the error C2228(VS19) in Menu.cpp/void `storeToArray()`?

```
#include"Train.h"

void storeToArray()
{
    Train* t;
    t = new Train();
    t.userInput;
    //collection.push_back(t);
}
```

> 1>Menu.cpp
> 1>C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\Menu.cpp(29,3): warning C4002: too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'assert'
> 1>C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\Menu.cpp(88,1): warning C4002: too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'assert'
> 1>C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\Menu.cpp(105,5): error C2039: 'userInput': is not a member of 'Train'
> 1>C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\train.h(7): message : see declaration of 'Train'

Does my way of solving this problem is optimal?
How can I make the program better?

https://github.com/brenqP/Course

Menu.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "PassengerTrain.h"
#include "FreightTrain.h"
#include "train.h"

void greeting();
void showMenu();
void userMenu();
void userInput();
void storeToArray();

//void printInput();
```

menu.cpp

```
#include "Menu.h"
#include "file.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

void greeting() { std::cout << "Welcome to the Train simulator!\n\n"; }
void showMenu()
{
    
    std::cout<< 
    "1)Create new train route for the passenger train.\n"<<
    "2)Create new train route for the freight train.\n"<<
    "3)Save results to the file.\n" <<
    "4)Open results from the file.\n" <<
    "5)Find train by number.\n"<<
    "6)Exit.\n\n";

}
void userMenu()
{
    
        showMenu();

        std::cout << "Choose one of the options by printing the number.\n";
        int option = 0;
        std::cin >> option;
        std::cout << "You have chosen the " << option << " option\n";
        assert("Invalid input.Please try again later.",option > 0 && option < 7);
        //system("cls");
        switch (option)
        {
        case 1:
        {//Train:: ;
            userInput();
            userMenu();

            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            userInput();
            userMenu();

            break;
        }
        case 3:
            storeToFile();
            userMenu();

            break;
        case 4:
            executeFile();
            userMenu();

            break;
        case 5:std::cout << "later";
            userMenu();

            break;
        case 6:
        {
            std::cout << "\nOkay, see you next time.\n";
            std::exit(0);
            break;
        }
        default:
            std::cout << "Something went wrong, please try again later\n";
            std::exit (0);
        }
}

void userInput()
{
    std::cout << "Input the number of the train you`re willing to create\n";
    int number = 0;
    std::cin >> number;
    assert(number > 0);
    std::cout << "Input the path of the train you`re willing to create\n"
        << "Ex. London-Paris\n";
    std::string path{ "N / A - N / A" };
    std::cin >> path;
    std::cout << "Input the time of the departure\n"
        << "Ex. 23.22\n";
    double time_of_departure{ 0 };
    std::cin >> time_of_departure;
    assert(time_of_departure >= 0 && time_of_departure < 24.0,
        "Invalid time of the departure ");
    //system("cls");
    Train g{ number,path,time_of_departure };
    g.print();

}
```

error

```
 void storeToArray()
    {
        Train* t;
        t = new Train();
        t.userInput;
        //collection.push_back(t);
    }
```

Train.cpp

```
#include "train.h"


Train::Train(int number, std::string path, double time_of_departure):
    m_number{ number },
    m_path{ path },
    m_time_of_departure{ time_of_departure }
{
}

Train::~Train()
{
}



//void Train::setPassengerTrain()
//{
//Train:setNumber();
//  
//}

void Train::setNumber(int number)
{
    m_number = number;
}

void Train::setPath(int path)
{
    m_path = path;
}

void Train::setTime_of_departure(int time_of_departure)
{
    m_time_of_departure = time_of_departure;
}



void Train::print()
{
    std::cout<< "The train number \t" <<
        getNumber() << " \t "<< 
        getPath() << " \tis departed at\t " << 
        //bug if there is a /t; print 121314 instead of 1
        getTime_of_departure()<<'\n' << std::endl;

}
```

train.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include<iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

class Train
{
protected:
    int m_number{0};
    std::string m_path{"N/A-N/A"};
    double m_time_of_departure{0};

    public :
    //some constructors
    Train() = default;
    Train(int number, std::string path, double time_of_departure);
    //destructor
    virtual ~Train();
    //void setPassengerTrain();
    
    virtual int getNumber() { return m_number; }
    void setNumber(int number);

    virtual std::string getPath() { return m_path; }
    void setPath(int path);

    virtual double getTime_of_departure(){ return m_time_of_departure; }
    void setTime_of_departure(int time_of_departure);

    void print();

};
```

PassengerTrain.h

```
    #pragma once
#include "train.h"


class PassengerTrain :public Train
{
    int m_number{ 0 };
    std::string m_path{ "N/A-N/A" };
    double m_time_of_departure{ 0 };
public:
    //some constructors
    PassengerTrain() = default;
    PassengerTrain(int number, std::string path, double time_of_departure);
    //destructor
     ~PassengerTrain();
    //void setPassengerTrain();
      int getNumber() { return m_number; }
    void setNumber(int number);

      std::string getPath() { return m_path; }
    void setPath(int path);

      double getTime_of_departure() { return m_time_of_departure; }
    void setTime_of_departure(int time_of_departure);

    void print();


};
```

PassengerTrain.cpp

```
    #include"PassengerTrain.h"



PassengerTrain::PassengerTrain(int number, std::string path, double time_of_departure):

        m_number{ number },
        m_path{ path },
        m_time_of_departure{ time_of_departure }{}

PassengerTrain::~PassengerTrain()
{
}

void PassengerTrain::print()
{
    std::cout << "The passenger train number \t" <<
        getNumber() << " \t " <<
        getPath() << " \tis departed at\t " <<
        //bug if there is a /t; print 121314 instead of 1
        getTime_of_departure() << '\n' << std::endl;
}
```

The freightTrain is the same as passengerTrain.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, with emphasis on the *minimal* part. And if asking about build errors then copy-paste the full and complete build output into the question itself, and add comments in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: One of the problems you ask about is that you use [`assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) wrong. Or rather, that you use it at all I would say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe not a complete answer (since you did not provide a minimally reproducible example to actually work on) but there are many obvious things to fix. Before even looking at details:

- C++ is case sensitive, `Train` and `train` are two different things to C++, this also applies to include files `Train.h` and `train.h`. You CANNOT mix those: fix.
- C++ is very flexible in terms of your text formatting, but in some places white-spaces are mandatory. In particular `#include"Train.h"` must be `#include "Train.h"`

Let's look at:

```
#include"Train.h"  // at white space --> #include "Train.h"

void storeToArray()
{
    Train* t;
    t = new Train();
    t.userInput;
    //collection.push_back(t);
}
```

where `userInput` is not a method or property of `Train` but a free function defined in `Menu.h`. Thus, very good practice is to also include `#include "Menu.h"` (this won't fix any of your problems yet).

Another issue is of course that `t` is a pointer, not an object. You cannot use the dot operator `t.`, but you have to use the arrow operate `t->`. But this also does not solve any of your problems yet.

It seems to me what you want to achieve is to ask the user for input, create a new Train object, and store it in a collection. For this you better start by changing the definition of `void userInput();` in `Menu.h` to `Train* userInput();`

Then in "menu.cpp" you also change it to `Train* userInput() {` and furthermore you change the last to lines of the userInput function from

```
    Train g{ number,path,time_of_departure };
    g.print();
```

(which actually does accomplish nothing useful) to

```
    Train* train = new Train(number, path, time_of_departure);
    train->print();
    return train;  // <-- this is really important since it return your train to the caller
```

If you do those changes, you at least can produce trains, and store them in a collection as you wish.